# Каково значение фразеологизма "началось в колхозе утро"?

Tags: фразеология

Вот, к примеру,  такая ситуация: утром торопливо исправляешь  что-нибудь неправильно написанное, а тебе говорят: «Началось на ферме утро…». Смешно…

**Фразеологизм, наверное, а что он обозначает?**  «Началось в колхозе утро…»  А вот значения разные:  большая суматоха, неодобрение и т.д.  **Но мне эти значения кажутся неточными.**

Вот поэты активно упражняются в стихах на заданную тему. Но откуда появилось это выражение, кто автор? Или это народный юмор?  Особенно интересно, почему всё происходит  утром. **Категория смешного именно в этом?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, что фраза "началось в колхозе утро" (началось в деревне утро; началось колхозье утро) имеет несколько значений.

1. Недостаток времени, нехватка рук именно утром — допустим, в большой семье: в школу, в детский сад, в ясли, на работу, проследить, поесть-попить, собрать, шнурки завязать, ничего не забыть, снова проследить.
   (Многие ведь так её и называют — "колхоз": *Всем колхозом придём* или *Весь колхоз с собой притащил*.)
2. Аврал, цейтнот или внеплановая работа.
   Начальник увидел в отчете ошибки, и началось в колхозе утро.
3. Неожиданно свалившиеся на голову неприятности.
   Жена сообщила, что в аварию попала, и началось в колхозе утро.
4. Суматоха, неразбериха, непонятная "движуха", необычное происшествие — состояние полного непонимания того, что происходит.
5. И, собственно, утро в деревне или на хуторе — начинается бурная жизнь: петухи горланят ни свет ни заря, гуси-утки гогочут и хлопают крыльями, коровы мычат и бренчат колокольцами, собаки всё это с гавканьем контролируют, журавль скрипит, ведро брякает, сенокосилка тарахтит...
   Всё это удивляет и нервирует нежного городского жителя. Он раздражен, не спит по утрам, его ожидания тишины и покоя обмануты: "Началось в колхозе утро!"

Выражение имеет не только неодобрительное значение, но и, как мне кажется, значение удивления, недоумения, растерянности, подтрунивания над самим собой.
А возникло, возможно, из последней ситуации: колхозов нет, а народный фразеологизм прижился.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, очень интересно. Значит, в основе фразеологизма лежит реальная утренняя деревенская суета, а если и есть что-нибудь смешное, то оно в переносном значении на другие ситуации, никак с колхозом не связанные.  Просто в основе комического лежит какое-нибудь несоответствие, а несоответствие    здесь именно в переносе.

Comment: Это сугубо мое личное мнение, основанное на собственном восприятии, воспоминаниях об утре и о работах на эстонском хуторе. И, конечно, жизненные ассоциации.

Comment: Именно это мне и нравится в Вашем ответе.

Answer (score 1):

﻿
[Большой словарь русских поговорок. — М: Олма Медиа Групп. В. М. Мокиенко, Т. Г. Никитина. 2007.](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/proverbs/26074/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C)

> Началось в колхозе утро
>   Жарг. мол. Неодобр. 1. О начале чего-л. нежелательного. Вахитов 2003, 110; Максимов, 191. 2. О начале какого-л. интенсивного действия, процесса. Вахитов 2003, 110.

Comment: Это я читала, мне как раз показался странным такой серьезный подход к значению выражения. Ведь неодобрение - это просто негативная оценка, а здесь скорее насмешка, юмор. И интенсивность процесса тоже обозначена с той же насмешкой, а в словаре этого нет.